# Dart Polymer & dart:js: getElementById() returns only [object Object]

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-polymer

When I execute this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script language="javascript">
        function foobar() {
           alert(document.getElementById("myPdf"));
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <object id="myPdf" type="application/pdf" data="file.pdf"></object>
      <input type="button" value="Click" onClick="return foobar();">
    </body>
  </html>
```

`[object] HTMLObjectElement` is alerted.

But doing the same thing with Dart Polymer in combination with dart:js, i.e. the object-element is added to the DOM via Dart Polymer and the javascript code is executed via `context.callMethod("foobar")`, only `[object] Object` is alerted. Why is this the case? How to get the more specific HTMLObjectElement in this case?

Comment: what you want in alert?

Comment: I used alert just for this example. All I want is that getElementById returns a HtmlObjectElement.

Comment: This question is not related to Dart, Polymer.Dart or dart2js as you are only writing Javascript and html in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution myself: The object has a property "impl", in which the HTMLObjectElement is stored.